# is there some design pattern in the code?

Tags: java, design-patterns

i look spring 3.05 source, and i found the class

```
public class ContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoader implements ServletContextListener{
    private ContextLoader contextLoader;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
       if(this.contextLoader  == null){
          this.contextLoader = this;
       }
       this.contextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
   }

}
```

why use the contextLoader field,why not just use this.initWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());?

is there some benefit from the useage?

Comment: Good question. I don't see any benefit. But looking at the source history, in Spring 2.5.6 I see that `ContextLoaderListener` was not a child class of `ContextLoader` and it had a method `createContextLoader()`(now deprecated) that returned an instance of `ContextLoader`. In current state, it extends `ContextLoader` and hence the this reference. See [this](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/2.5.6/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.java/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should belong to Code Review stack exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you found that code, but the source for `ContextLoaderListener` for Spring 3.0.5 (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.java/), for example) has this code:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    this.contextLoader = createContextLoader();
    if (this.contextLoader == null) {
        this.contextLoader = this;
    }
    this.contextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
}
```

You left out the first line of the method!

Comment: `createContextLoader()` was deprecated and will be eventually removed

Comment: @Sundeep - OP is asking specifically about 3.0.5, where it's still present in the code (although deprecated).

Comment: Oops. My bad. The method returns null since its been deprecated.

Comment: @Sundeep - In later releases, the entire method body is a single line: `initWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());`.